# Issue with EventBridge rule for aws.events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I want to send to CloudWatch logs ALL the events sent to a custom event bus.

I created the custom event bus: `my-event-bus`

I created the CloudWatch log group

I created the event bus policy so everyone within my account can put an event into `my-event-bus`

I created a rule for that custom bus

This is the rule:

```
  MyRuleForBus:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Description: Testing rule
      EventBusName: 
      Name: testing-rule-for-my-event-bus
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.events
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        - Arn: arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:MY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:my-event-bus-log-group
          Id: 'my-bus'
```

When I try to put an event
`aws events put-events --entries file://put-events.json`

I receive the following error

```
{
    "FailedEntryCount": 1,
    "Entries": [
        {
            "ErrorCode": "NotAuthorizedForSourceException",
            "ErrorMessage": "Not authorized for the source."
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the content of `put-events.json`

```json
[
    {
      "Source": "aws.events",
      "EventBusName": "my-event-bus",
      "Detail": "{ \"key1\": \"value3\", \"key2\": \"value4\" }",
      "Resources": [
        "resource1",
        "resource2"
      ],
      "DetailType": "myDetailType"
     }
  ]
```

But, if I change the source to other, for example, 'hello', in both, the rule and the event it works.

**What am I doing wrong?**
I want to make it work with `aws.events` so all the events sent to this bus end in CloudWatch (target)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`aws.events` **belongs to AWS**, not to you, thus you can't define it as source of your events. Only AWS can do it.

You need to use your own **custom name** for the source of your events, e.g. `myapp.events`.

Comment: As always you are totally right. Thanks, Marcin. After re-reading the docs and with your review, it does make sense.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: Can you share the link the docs please? Where you saw this